# Chrome not handling multiple floats in WebGL buffer? Fine in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I am working with a buffer that passes in a few different elements, below is a crude diagram of where each element appears in the buffer:

```
 pos col amb dif spe nor uv t a s
+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+-+-+-+
0   3   6   9   1   1   1  2 2 2 2
                2   5   8  0 1 2 3
```

Where

```
pos - the vertex (3 floats)
col - the color at that vertex (note, this is a legacy variable that is unused(3 floats)
amb - the ambient RGB reflection of the model (3 floats)
dif - the diffuse RGB reflection of the model (3 floats)
spe - the specular RGB reflection of the model (3 floats) 
nor - the normals of the model (3 floats)
uv - the uv coordinates to the mapped texture (2 floats)
t - a pointer to which texture to load (a float)
a - the transparency (alpha) of the model (a float)
s - the specular exponent (a float)
```

My buffer looks something like this:

```
// stride = how many floats to skip each round (times 4)
stride = 23 * 4;
// Last parameter = where this attribute starts in the buffer
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 0 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_color,    3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 3 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_ambient,  3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 6 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_diffuse,  3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 9 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_specular, 3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 12 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_normals,  3, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 15 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_uvs,      2, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 18 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_tex,      1, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 20 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_a,        1, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 21 * 4) ;
GL.vertexAttribPointer(_shine,    1, GL.FLOAT, false, stride, 22 * 4) ;
```

All three floats are being passed the same way in the vertex shader:

```
attribute float tex;
attribute float a;
attribute float shine;
...
varying float vTex;
varying float vA;
varying float vShine;

void main(void) {
    ...
    vTex = tex;
    vA = a;
    vShine = shine;
```

I'm passing everything fine, literally copy/pasted the `_tex` code for `_a` and `_shine`. No errors are popping up and if I print the array containing all these values, everything is getting stored properly. Likewise, `_tex` is being used inside the fragment shader without error.

```
void main(void) {
    vec4 texColor;
    //Ambient
    vec4 Ia = La * Ka;

    // Diffuse
    vec4 Id = Kd;
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(world_light - vertex);
    vec3 L = normalize(lightDirection - world_pos);
    vec3 N = normalize(world_norm);
    float lambert = max(0.0, dot(N, -L));
    Id = Kd*Ld*lambert;

    // Specular
    vec4 Is = Ks;
    vec3 V = normalize(vertex - world_pos);
    vec3 H = normalize(L + V);
    float NdotH = dot(N, H);

    NdotH = max(NdotH, 0.0);
    NdotH = pow(NdotH, 10.0);
    // NdotH = pow(NdotH, vShine); <-------------------------------- ERRORS
    Is = Ks*Ls*NdotH;
    if (vTex < 0.1) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture01, vUV);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb, texColor.a);
    } else if (vTex < 1.1) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture02, vUV);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb, texColor.a);
    } else if (vTex < 2.1) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture03, vUV);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb, texColor.a);
    } else {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture04, vUV);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb, texColor.a);
    }

    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (Ia*A) + (Id*D) + (Is*S);
```

The second I flip to `NdotH = pow(NdotH, vShine);`, Chrome's WebGL will crash with the following error message:

```
VM258:1958 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked(anonymous function) @ VM258:1958
    gl.getUniformLocation @ VM258:4629
    main @ texturize.js:569
    onload @ (index):26
VM258:1958 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked(anonymous function) @ VM258:1958
    gl.getUniformLocation @ VM258:4629
    main @ texturize.js:570
    onload @ (index):26
```

This is obviously the confusing part, as the floats are attributes, not uniforms. Again, loading in Firefox is fine, but I am trying to understand what is causing problems on the Chrome front and what the resolution is without having to refactor.

I'm hesitant to post full code, as this is a class assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that rearranging vShine and vTex in the buffer will cause a similar problem. That is, I can use vShine if it appears first, but any attempt to use vTex will cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, it is specifically a limitation to Chrome's cap on Max Varying Vectors, discovered via here: https://www.browserleaks.com/webgl

The issue on why Chrome cannot handle things is I am pushing to many different vectors to a single buffer, while Firefox can handle 30, Chrome can only handle 9. Since I am at this cusp, that is where my error is coming from.

Comment: But why would Chrome report a different cap than Firefox when they are running on the same hardware? Check *Max vertex uniform vectors" on Chrome, is it 253 (in stead of, say, 4096)? That means Chrome is on software rendering, your graphics card/driver might be on the blacklist.

Comment: Potentially, when I was working on this, I resolved it by merging _tex, _a, and _shine into a single vec3 attribute. Doing this removed the errors.

Comment: Referring back to browserleaks.com shows Chrome matching Firefox in specifications, which was not the case at the time of writing this post. I don't believe I updated my drivers in the past two weeks, so I am unsure as to the cause of the change.